# Reading ID cards in the web

Tags: javascript, web, reader, id-card

I'm interested in being able to read ID cards(Belgian ID cards if that matters) using the idcard reader.

After some research I came across [this blog](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/using-auth0-and-the-belgian-eid-card-to-secure-your-webcloudangularjs-applications/) which seems great, but it does require *.NET* to be able to run. I also found [e-contract](http://e-contract.be/products.html) which allows us to do the same, but it does require *jboss*.

However, I would want to implement it with Salesforce, so I would prefer using HTML/JS and any JS libraries needed.

Is there any library/trick that I can use to be able to read the data from the microchip directly into browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: From [the EID developers guide](http://eid.belgium.be/en/binaries/UPD_Developers_Guide_tcm406-112228.pdf), it looks like you can only use C++, Java and dotNet languages. It does not look very promising for JS in this matter :/

Comment: @blex thanks for your reply. I've seen it and that's why I asked if there is any library or trick to bypass it.

Comment: Did you find anything? Looking for the same thing.

Comment: @bertvh nope. It was decided to let Java do it and then send the info to the server. Although I'm pretty sure there should be a way to do it in a web page, I did not find it and never looked into it since then

Comment: @Novarg Any solutions for this?

Comment: @Boky nope, did not find it. It was decided to use Java and then send the request to the server

Comment: @Novarg Ok, thanks.

Comment: i know this is an old question but did you find any solution?